# How do I apply a regex substitution in a string column of a DataFrame?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, substitution

I have a DataFrame called "Animals" that looks like this:

```
 Words
 The Black Cat
 The Red Dog
```

I want to add a plus sign before each word so that it looks like this:

```
 Words
 +The +Black +Cat
 +The +Red +Dog
```

I have tried this using regex but it did not work:

```
 df = re.sub(r'([a-z]+)', r'+\1', Animals)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `str.replace` with the following regex to make the change to all rows of the column:

```
df.Words = df.Words.str.replace(r'(\b\S)', r'+\1')
```

The DataFrame then looks like this:

```
>>> df
              Words
0  +The +Black +Cat
1    +The +Red +Dog
```

Comment: Very good, thank for for the solution.  I know not part of the original question but was wondering whether this could also be adapted to remove white space between words?

Comment: @user3682157: no problem, glad it helped. To remove all of the whitespace you could perhaps use `df.Words.str.replace(r'\s', r'')`.